# Is there a way to turn one monitor off in a dual-head setup?

Tags: xorg, dpms

Is there a DPMS option to turn one monitor off in a dual-head setup? I know the following can turn both off:

```
xset dpms force off
```

Comment: Try the power button? :D

Comment: That won't force the window manager to keep things on one display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xrandr --output $NAMEOFDISPLAY --off`

Comment: That's probably a good idea. I want this for reading [on one monitor -- I have two set up vertically] ... at first I was thinking of something interruptable like dpms, but that would probably be too interruptable, and I could always hotkey it it turn back on. Thanks. Unfortunately my desktop is using nvidia twinview, so is xrandr ineligible :(.

Comment: This is not really the same as DPMS-off: this resizes virtual desktop, whic is quite an intrusive change, since all the windows will be moved from their places to the remaining "visible" monitors. Though it seems the OP wanted exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the nvidia driver, you can use twinview metamodes. You can find everything in the driver   [manual](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/180.22/README/chapter-13.html). After configuring, you can switch by using

```
xrandr -s 1
```

or use a 0 if you want to switch back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ddccontrol](https://superuser.com/a/1640847/637466) to control **dpms** on individual monitors – **without** modifying the virtual desktop (→ moving windows etc.).

See [my answer on a question that explicitly asked for this behaviour](https://superuser.com/a/1640847/637466).